# How to get Seed or pwDerivedKey with upload keystore from eth-lightwallet?

Tags: wallets

```
              <html>

                <body>
                    <script src="./lightwallet.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="web3.js"></script>

                <form id="signup" method="POST" action="upload.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"  accept=".json" >
              </form>



          <h1>LightWallet</h1>
                        <h2>New Wallet</h2>
                        <div>
   <input type="text" id="userEntropy" placeholder="Type random text to generate entropy" size="80"></input>
                        <button onClick="newWallet()">Create New Wallet</button>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Restore Wallet</h2>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="seed" value="" size="80"></input>
                        <button onClick="setSeed()">Restore wallet from Seed</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="addr"></div>
                    <div>
                        <button onClick='getBalances()'>Refresh</button>
                    </div>


                     <script>
                    var web3 = new Web3();
                    var global_keystore;
                    if (!web3.currentProvider)
                        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://XXXXXXXX'));

                    function newAddresses(password) {
                        if (password == '') {
                            password = prompt('Enter password to retrieve addresses', 'Password');
                        }
                        global_keystore.keyFromPassword(password, function(err, pwDerivedKey){
                            if(err) throw err;
                            global_keystore.generateNewAddress(pwDerivedKey, 1);
                            var address = global_keystore.getAddresses()[0];
                            document.getElementById('functionCaller').innerHTML = ''
                            document.getElementById('functionCaller').innerHTML += '0x' + address 
                            getBalances();
                        });
                    }

                    function getBalances() {
                        var address = global_keystore.getAddresses()[0];
                        document.getElementById('addr').innerHTML = ''
                        web3.eth.getBalance(address, function(err, balance) {
                            web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0x' + address, function(err, nonce) {
                                document.getElementById('addr').innerHTML += '<div>0x' + address + ' (Bal: ' + (balance / 1.0e18) + ' ETH, Nonce: ' + nonce + ')' + '</div>'
                            });
                        });      
                    }

                    function setSeed() {
                        var password = prompt('Enter Password to encrypt your seed', 'Password');
                        lightwallet.keystore.createVault({ password: password , seedPhrase: document.getElementById('seed').value, hdPathString: "m/44'/60'/0'/0"} , function(err, keystore){

                            global_keystore = keystore;
                            document.getElementById('seed').value = ''
                            newAddresses(password);
                        });
                    }

                    function newWallet() {
                        var extraEntropy = document.getElementById('userEntropy').value;
                        document.getElementById('userEntropy').value = '';
                        var randomSeed = lightwallet.keystore.generateRandomSeed(extraEntropy);
                        console.log('GGGG: ', randomSeed);
                        var infoString = 'Your new wallet seed is: "' + randomSeed +
                            '". Please write it down on paper or in a password manager, you will need it to access your wallet. Do not let anyone see this seed or they can take your Ether. ' +
                            'Please enter a password to encrypt your seed while in the browser.'
                        var password = prompt(infoString, 'Password');
                        lightwallet.keystore.createVault({ password: password, seedPhrase: randomSeed , hdPathString: "m/44'/60'/0'/0"} , function(err, keystore){
                            global_keystore = keystore;
                            newAddresses(password);
                        });
                    }

                    function functionCall() {
                        var fromAddr = document.getElementById('functionCaller').innerHTML
                        var contractAddr = document.getElementById('contractAddr').value
                        var abi = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('contractAbi').value)
                        var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddr)
                        var functionName = document.getElementById('functionName').value
                        var args = JSON.parse('[' + document.getElementById('functionArgs').value + ']')
                        var valueEth = document.getElementById('sendValueAmount').value
                        var value = parseFloat(valueEth) * 1.0e18
                        var gasPrice = 50000000000
                        var gas = 3141592

                        web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddr, function(err, nonce){
                            var funcTx = lightwallet.txutils.functionTx(abi, functionName, [], {to: contractAddr, gasLimit: 300000, gasPrice: gasPrice , nonce: nonce, value: value });
                            var password = prompt('Enter Password to sign Transaction', 'Password');
                            global_keystore.keyFromPassword(password, function(err, pwDerivedKey){
                                //sign tx NIC LIN
                                var signedTx = lightwallet.signing.signTx(global_keystore, pwDerivedKey, funcTx, global_keystore.getAddresses()[0]);
                                console.log("signedTx: " + signedTx.toString('hex'));

                                //send tx NIC LIN
                                web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, tx_id){
                                    console.log(tx_id);
                                });
                            });

                        });
                    }
                    </script>

                </body>

                </html>
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

On [their github repo](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) it says you get the `pwDerivedKey` from password like this:

```
const pwDerivedKey = keystore.keyFromPassword(password, callback)
```

Using that you can get the seed:

```
const seed = keystore.getSeed(pwDerivedKey)
```